# MOD Rewrite Mask for Image URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

Okay so I am launching a cloned e-commerce site.  I want to create a rewrite rule for the image folder for the second site to fetch images from the first site.

RewriteRule ^alice.gif$ www.rhinomart.com/images/h_home.gif

When I go to alice.gif directly through the browser it simply redirects me to the rhinomart.com URL and image.  How do I prevent the redirect from occurring?  When I go to http://www.acnbiz.net/alice.gif it should fetch alice.gif directly from Rhinomart.com/images and not redirect.  is it possible???

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rewrite to an external site but not redirect the browser then you will need to proxy the request by enabling `mod_proxy` and using the `[P]` flag.

Comment: I ended up figuring out the ultimate solution!  MOD_ALIAS allows you to setup a server side redirect so the client never actually sees the target domain it's fetching the images from.  

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html
It was real simple, from SSH:
1. locate httpd.conf (find your active httpd.conf)
2. vi httpd.conf
3. scroll down to your virtual domain and add the following code:
AliasMatch ^/images(.*) /usr/local/htdocs/yoursite/images/$1 
or whatever the real path is

Took me a while to find this solution, Even my hosting company couldn't help me with this one.